# Is there an Angular2 equivalent to injecting $filter to access a filter in your code?

Tags: angular, filter

In Angular 1.x, I was able to inject $filter and do something like this in my JavaScript/TypeScript code:

```
formattedDate = $filter('date')(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Is there an equivalent in Angular 2?

Comment: Are you looking for [pipes](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html)? They're the first hit for *"Angular2 equivalent of filter"*.

Comment: I found info on pipes, but only on creating my own, not how I'd access the ones built into Angular 2, except for accessing them from within HTML.

Comment: They work with regular A2 DI, or you can just `new` some of them up.

Comment: ^^ pretty much word-for-word dupe. Please do research things before asking.

Comment: I did a fair amount of searching, I didn't just blurt out the question. I obviously didn't stumble on the right wording for my search, however.